# Pass variable from php POST to PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs

I'm trying to pass two variables between the php file they are posted to, and the js file that phantomjs runs. my code is below

```
<?php
$user = "name@domain.com";
$pass = "Password123";
$output = shell_exec('phantomjs login.js '.$user.' '.$pass.'');
?>
```

and the js

```
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;
console.log(args);
phantom.exit();
```

and the result, which is a seemingly inexplicably trimmed version of what I want, with beginning and end characters missing:

```
[".js,name@domain.com,Passwo",",name@domain.com,Pas"]
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to make sure the data are not trimmed in the transfer process?

Comment: try like this:-$output = shell_exec("phantomjs login.js","$user", "$pass");

Comment: Please don't use stack snippets to paste code that is not runnable in the browser. Simply indend the code with 4 spaces or select the code and press Ctrl+K.

Comment: When I try it that way, I get "[false, false]". Thoughts?

Comment: Try quoting the arguments :
`$output = shell_exec('phantomjs login.js "'.$user.'" "'.$pass.'" ');`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue at all with PHP 5.4 & PhantomJS 1.9.7/2.0.1 except that your php code is missing the output of `$output`